# Device which will turn off my water motor automatically after the tanks are full

Tags: home-automation, water

I have to build a system which automatically turns off my water motor after the tanks are full. I already have build up a system which lights up a bulb and an electric bell and tells me that the tanks are full. Now I want the water motor to be switched off automatically after the tanks are full. Is there some a device I can make which will turn off the water motor automatically after filling the water tanks.

Comment: Hook a relay into your light/sound system, that will turn your motors off.

Comment: You might look for float switches... I only know of ones that turn my sump pump on when the water is high.. But I figure they would make the opposite too.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, those types of float switches are certainly available. These types of switches, like all switches, are either *normally open* or *normally closed*, so they will either open or close when floated.

Comment: Seems like a simple relay is all you need (assuming "water motor" means an electric water pump).  Depending on how you rig your alarm system it would be either normally open (so that the motor runs only when the light is lit) or normally closed (so that the motor runs when the light is not lit.  Or you can use a simple float switch, which connects the sensor float directly to the motor switch.  (Though be aware that most float switches will operate backwards from what you want.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for fancy electronics here.  Look for something called a *float switch*.  Various types are readily available in hardware stores.

I have one of these turning on a sump pump in a bucket that my basement sink drains into.  In this case I have a float (a small re-purposed pickle jar if I remember right) connected to a threaded vertical shaft.  That shaft has two pair of opposing nuts on it, which are the stops to activate the float switch to click between on and off.  I can adjust the water level for on and off by adjusting where the nuts are on the threaded shaft.

In my case, the shaft going higher turns on the switch since I'm trying to empty the tank, not fill it.  However, I could have mounted the switch upside down to get the effect you want.  Most switches are either mechanically symmetric so that you can mount them either way, or are available in *normally open* and *normally closed* options.

Comment: Thank you Olin. Can you send me a diagram so that i can understand better and make it myself at home.

Answer (score 0):

If the tank is a sealed system use a pump/pressure switch in the pipe line, these are common and commercially made for household water systems.  They include a mechanical relay which is controlled by the water pressure high & low points.

Example:
http://www.zoro.com/i/G2713557/?utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Google_Shopping_Feed&gclid=COaXi-_c38MCFVFp7AodnlgAgw

If the system is open then use the float device switch as described by the other replies.

Example:
http://www.zoro.com/g/Float%20Switch/00086553/

Answer (score 0):

There are many water level controller devices available in the market that can automatically turn off motor when the tank is fully filled with water.

Find this controller on Amazon: [RMG Automatic Water Level Controller for Motor Pump Operated by Switch/MCB upto 1.5 HP - Tank only](https://www.amazon.in/RMG-Automatic-Controller-Operated-Switch/dp/B00RKF6AZW)

Also for water motor comparison check the Industrial matrix website: [Industrial Matrix: Electric Motor Catalog](https://www.industrialmatrix.com/).

Comment: it is [customary here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6636/does-this-constitute-spam) to disclose affiliation with a company. It looks like you are affiliated with Industrial Matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Float switches but I found them to be a bit unreliable. I have also used the RMg Automation water level controllers and such devices work perfectly and are reliable for long operation times: I have used it, say for 3 years without no issues.